# Subtractor using op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, linear

I need to create a subtractor on LT spice using an LT1028A to emulate the difference between 90V and 23V; resulting in 67V. I have tried using a variety of resistance pairs, but in vain. Could anyone kindly help, the output is stagnant at 15.84V?

Vo = (V2 - V1); I have used R1 = R2; R3 = R4

[image]
Pic Courtesy: Getty Images, 2014

Comment: If that's not your drawing or design then you need to credit it. (This is [site policy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).) Hit the [edit] link. What voltage do you realistically think you can apply to your op-amp's input terminals and what voltage can you get from the output of a typical op-amp?

Comment: I get your point, that its only going to work with around 1V, thingies but tell me what should I do. Should I forget it and just use a behaviourial voltage instead?

Comment: (1) What is the real problem you are trying to solve? (2) I never heard of "a behavioural voltage". What do you mean by the term?

Comment: None of the standard opamps is capable of giving an output of ~60VDC. You get 15.84V because the opamp's output is saturating, which means that the output hits nearly the positive supply rail *(an opamp's max output is the positive supply voltage, in theory. In practice, there's always a non-zero margin between the max output voltage and the positive supply voltage)*.

Comment: @RohatKılıç yeah man I just realised..

Comment: @Transistor just trying to subtract to midstage outputs

Comment: (1) Midstage of what? (You're not making it easy to help.) (2) Why? What are you going to do with the result?